# Problem resizing image using Code Ignitor1.7.3

Tags: php, codeigniter

Following is the code which resize the image, but here i am not able to resize the image

```
function processHome(){  
    $this->load->library('image_lib');

    $img_path =  base_url().'img/image/50X50/ori.jpeg';

    $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
    $config['source_image'] = $img_path;
    $config['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
    $config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
    $config['width'] = 50;
    $config['height'] = 50;

    $this->load->library('image_lib', $config);  
    $this->image_lib->resize();

    if ( ! $this->image_lib->resize()){
        echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();
    }

    echo "No error";
    exit;

    $this->load->view('index', $data); 
}
```

Comment: Does that give you any error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a start, remove the

```
$this->load->library('image_lib');
```

at the beginning - you only need to load the library once, and only after you set the parameters.

Then, give the relative/server path to your image folder, instead of the url - as in, no base_url().

Finally, check the permissions for the folder the image is in - it must be readable/writable by all, and php should be allowed to create new files.

I guess that's all.

Comment: Hi i moved this $this->load->library('image_lib');
to Controller constructor and  added relative path $img_path =  realpath("img")."\\images\\50X50\\ori.jpeg"; check all the permission but still its not resize the file

Comment: try *removing* $this->load->library('image_lib') completely: the library has to be loaded with arguments, as you do in $this->load->library('image_lib', $config).