# How to resize image in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

i am using codeigniter upload library and i want to resize the image. but when I run the code it save the image but its not resizing the image. here is my php code:

```
                 $this->load->library('upload');

                 $config['upload_path'] = APPPATH .'../images/student';
                 $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpeg|jpg|png';
                 $config['max_size']      = '2000';
                 $config['maintain_ratio']= FALSE;
                 $config['master_dim']    = 'auto';
                 $config['width']         = 128;
                 $config['height']        = 128;
                 $config['overwrite']     = FALSE;
                 //initialize
                 $this->upload->initialize($config);
```

Comment: what is the effect of $config['overwrite']     = FALSE; ? I am also asking

Comment: Do you get an error? Does it successfully upload the image?

Comment: yeah the image is successfully uploaded but it will not resizing , no i don't have any errors

Comment: overwirte: when there is a duplicate image with the same name it will not replace it

Comment: Do you call:  `$this->image_lib->resize()`? Where do you set the image library? Read here: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/image_lib.html

Comment: the image_lib with resize() function will resize the existence image in my folder. but my question is when i uploading the image resize the image and then save it to the folder(if there is any way to do it?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by [@relentless](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14610787/how-to-resize-image-in-codeigniter#comment20402158_14610890) you need to use the [Image Manipulation Class](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/image_lib.html). The upload class is only helping you to upload the image, not resize it.

The width and height configurations are there to restrict the size of the image you can upload.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to use the following:

```
$config['max_width']  = '128';
$config['max_height']  = '128';
```

note the `max_width` not `width`

Comment: when i change it to this code i got an error it says: "The image you are attempting to upload exceedes the maximum height or width." i just want to resize the image to 128x128. thanks for your answer but it dose not work

Comment: See if this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4496428/problem-resizing-image-using-code-ignitor1-7-3?rq=1